# What is the equivalent of “getTickFrequency” from OpenCV in C# EmguCV?

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I am converting this code from C++ to C#

```
double freq = getTickFrequency() / 1000;
```

I can't find the equivalent of `getTickFrequency` in EmguCV in C#.

Comment: I don't know anything about emucv, but in plain old .Net, System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.Frequency is what I'd use

Comment: I don't think they are the same.

Comment: Probably not, but they are both going to deal with the clock quantum. With a little experimentation you might find a relationship. Then again, with modern multicore, hyperthreaded, variable clock-rate processors, who knows how all this fits together now.

Comment: I tested something called QueryPerformanceFrequency - from OpenCV code for this getTickFrequency - and it showed the exact result as System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.Frequency. Probably you are right. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like my previous question, I didn't find an explicit function for `getTickFrequency` in `EmguCV`. The only solution I found is to rewrite the function using the open source of `OpenCV` [OpenCV Core](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/system.cpp)

```
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
private static extern bool QueryPerformanceFrequency(out long lpFrequency);
double GetTickFrequency()
{
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(out long freq);
    return (double)freq;
}
```

I thing `EmguCV` should be revised to add these missing parts with good documentation.